# HTML - CSS - How to left-align images in a centered and resizable parent

Tags: javascript, html, css, alignment

I have a lot of thumbnails in my page: I want them to be centered, but the last line looks awful while resizing and I have something like one or two orphan images floating in the center of the page.

The last line should be left-aligned.
How to do it?
I tried to insert another div with "margin:0 auto 0 auto;" but it doesn't work.

https://jsfiddle.net/4hw4fkm9/

What I try to have:
[image: What I try to have]

```
<div style="text-align:center;">
    <img />
    <img />
    <img />
    <img />
    etc..
</div>
```

Comment: _"The last line should be left-aligned."_ You mean based on your code it should be, or you just would like it to be?

Comment: I'm just talking about the result, not literally

Comment: @GCW I bet your images are in different sizes.

Comment: @GCW can you post another image for what you want to have?

Comment: I just did it, look at the question

Answer (score 1):

You should use CSS for this, not the HTML attribute "align", which is pretty old school. You can either float the images left, in which case they will stack to the left, or you could set all the images to display: inline-block, then use text-align: center on their container element (the div in this case).

Here are some references: 
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

Comment: I just want the last images to be aligned to the lef margin of my main block. Look at the fiddle.

Comment: Right, so if you use the float solution, they will be:
https://jsfiddle.net/4tofousc/2/ Blurgh, wrong link. Fixed.

Comment: And this is not what I want. I need to have the same margins on left and right, also resizing, and the last images aligned to left instead of center.

Comment: Yeah, you'd need the bounding container in jswebb's answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for - as you mention that you both 'want them centered' but want them left-aligned, too.

What you can do is create another `div` that will act as a container, set `width: 100%` on the main div, set the width slightly lower on the container div and set `margin: 0 auto;` on the container. Then make the images relatively positioned with `left:0;`.

[See Updated Fiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/4hw4fkm9/4/). Is this what you're after?

**EDIT:** [Re-Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4hw4fkm9/5/) for my attached comment. You can use set pixel values on the main and container `div` to account for the set pixel width of the thumbnails + any spacing that occurs.

Comment: the container is not centered in the page. I updated the question with a picture

Comment: The container is centered in the page; however, the issue is that the thumbnails have a set pixel width, while the rest is percentages - so, if you get to a point where the space left on a line is <100px, it won't look centered because the thumbnails can't fit.

A solution would be to figure out the exact pixel make-up of each thumbnail, and then make both the main div and the container div have set pixel values, too - having measurements that will allow the thumbnail width + any padding, etc. to go evenly into it.

https://jsfiddle.net/4hw4fkm9/5/ - Fiddle Update. What about this?

Comment: I can't use this solution, I'm working on bootstrap fluid grids

Answer (score 0):

Using the selectors in the fiddle.

```
.center {
    text-align:center;
    background-color:red;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0 20px;
}

.center:after{
    content:'';
    display:table;
    clear:both;
}

img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    float:left;
}
```

From there the .center element would need a width of some multiple of 100px to include a fixed number of imgs.  I added padding to make it look closer to the picture you provided.